Divergence of canonical energy-momentum tensor in QFT
I have to show that the divergence of the canonical energy-momentum tensor is zero, i.e. $$\partial^{\mu}T_{\mu\nu} = 0.$$
The Lagrangian is $$\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}\partial^{\mu} \phi \partial_{\mu} \phi - \frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2 - \lambda \phi^4$$ and for the energy-momentun tensor I got $$ T_{\mu\nu} = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial^{\mu}\phi)} \partial_{\nu} \phi - \mathcal{L} g_{\mu\nu} = \partial_{\mu} \phi \partial_{\nu}\phi - \mathcal{L} g_{\mu\nu}.$$
Then I calculate the divergence as follows:
$$\begin{aligned} \partial^{\mu}T_{\mu\nu} &= \partial^{\mu} \left( \partial_{\mu}\phi \partial_{\nu}\phi - \mathcal{L} g_{\mu\nu} \right) \\ &= \partial^{\mu} \left( \partial_{\mu} \phi \partial_{\nu} \phi \right) - \partial^{\mu} g_{\mu\nu} \mathcal{L}  \\ &= \partial^{\mu} \left( \partial_{\mu} \phi \partial_{\nu} \phi \right) - \partial^{\mu} g_{\mu\nu} \left( \frac{1}{2}\partial^{\mu} \phi \partial_{\mu} \phi - \frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2 - \lambda \phi^4 \right) \\ &= \partial_{\nu} \phi \left( \partial^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} \phi \right) + \partial_{\mu}\phi \left( \partial^{\mu} \partial_{\nu} \phi \right) - \frac{1}{2}  \partial_{\nu} \left( \partial^{\mu} \phi \partial_{\mu} \phi - m^2 \phi^2 - 2\lambda \phi^4 \right) \\ &= \Box \phi \partial_{\nu} \phi + \partial_{\mu}\phi \partial^{\mu} \partial_{\nu} \phi - \frac{1}{2} \left( \partial_{\mu} \phi \partial_{\nu} \partial^{\mu} \phi + \partial^{\mu} \phi \partial_{\nu} \partial_{\mu} \phi - 2 m^2 \phi \partial_{\nu} \phi - 2 \cdot 4 \lambda \phi^3 \partial_{\nu} \phi \right) \\ &= \Box \phi \partial_{\nu} \phi + \partial_{\mu}\phi \partial_{\nu} \partial^{\mu} \phi - \frac{1}{2} \partial_{\mu} \phi \partial_{\nu} \partial^{\mu} \phi - \frac{1}{2} \partial^{\mu} \phi \partial_{\nu} \partial_{\mu} \phi + m^2 \phi \partial_{\nu} \phi + 4 \lambda \phi^2 \phi \partial_{\nu} \phi \\ &= \left( \Box + m^2 + 4 \lambda \phi^4 \right) \phi \partial_{\nu} \phi + \frac{1}{2} \partial_{\mu} \phi \partial_{\nu} \partial^{\mu} \phi - \frac{1}{2} \partial^{\mu} \phi \partial_{\nu} \partial_{\mu} \phi .\end{aligned}$$
At this point I'm stuck. What I know is that the term $ \left( \Box + m^2 + 4 \lambda \phi^4 \right) \phi$ without the $4 \lambda \phi^2$ would be the Klein-Gordon Equation, which is $0$. But here I'm not sure what to do with that $4 \lambda \phi^2$ term, if this is even the problem.
Also, the second and third term should somehow cancel (at least I think so), but I'm not sure how.
Any help would be much appreciated!

You need the equation of motion. Only if this holds is the divergency zero.

@my2cts I found that for the Klein-Gordon field the equation of motion is exactly $\left( \Box + m^2 \right) \phi = 0$. But how do I find it for the Lagrangian that I have ?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_(field_theory)#Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equations

So I have to rewrite the terms that I got left in the last step in such a way that I get the equation of motion, i.e. Euler-Lagrange equation? Or do You mean something else?

I mean you have to use the Euler-Lagrange equation. You do not need the explicit form for $\mathcal L$, you just need the Euler-Lagrange equation. And you will also have to use the fact that partial derivatives commute.

Also, one of your equations has a bare $\partial^\mu \partial_\mu\partial_\nu$ that is not acting on anything. That is a typo you should fix.


the energy-momentun tensor I got $$ T_{\mu\nu} = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial^{\mu}\phi)} \partial_{\nu} \phi - \mathcal{L} g_{\mu\nu}
$$

The above equation is all you need. You do not need the explicit form of your phi-fourth lagrangian.
$$
\partial^\mu T_{\mu\nu} = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial^{\mu}\phi)} \partial^\mu\partial_{\nu} \phi 
+ (\partial^\mu \phi) \partial_{\nu}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial^{\mu}\phi)} 
-  g_{\mu\nu}\partial^\mu\mathcal{L}
$$
$$
= \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial^{\mu}\phi)} \partial^\mu\partial_{\nu} \phi 
+ (\partial^\mu \phi) \partial_{\nu}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial^{\mu}\phi)} 
-  g_{\mu\nu}\left(
\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi}\partial^\mu\phi
+\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial \partial^\alpha\phi}\partial^\mu\partial^\alpha\phi
\right)\tag{1}
$$
I cannot in good conscience do any more of your homework for you.
From Eq. (1) continue by collecting together some of the terms (two of which clearly cancel by commutation of partial derivative) and apply the equation of motion to cancel the remaining two terms.

I am not sure from where you got the impression that I need that "somebody does my homework" for me, nor is that in any shape or form my goal, since I have to learn it and understand it. I presented the method how I tried it and asked for help, not finished homework. The fact that I didn't consider an non-explicit method and using the Euler-Lagrange equations is in this case my "error". But again, I asked for help. Not a solution of my homework.
Regardless, thanks for the answer.

The OP doth protest too much, methinks.

I suggest you stick it to physics and you do not have to respond to someone if you think they are looking for the easy way out. To be honest, I expect more than you show here from people on this forum. Gladly most of the response was not like yours so I happily see it as an exception rather than a rule.

@syphracos nobody implied you are "looking for an easy way out". I don't know why you are so belligerent, but I would recommend toning this behaviour down.

@paulina well I personally consider when somebody does my homework as an easy way out. The proper way is to try it yourself and, if stuck, eventually ask for some help/advice. Hope that we can agree on that. Since he wrote "I cannot in good conscience do any more of your homework for you", it coincides with my opinion that this would seem like I search for an easy way out. I do not see anything wrong in defending my goal, which was advice, not a solution. Regarding the second message, since this is a physics forum and I personally am not an english speaker

@paulina nor am I familiar with the "doth protest too much, methinks" quote, which I had to look up and see what it means, I responded the way which I did. And I stay by it. I was seeking help/advice, not a solution. And I want to keep it in the realm of physics, not literature (like I said, I had to look up the quote).
